# FasterXML Jackson's JSON polymorphism with JsonSubTypes and JsonTypeInfo

Tags: java, json, polymorphism, jackson, fasterxml

This is a popular problem for FasterXML's Jackon JSON developers. I faced it when I had with similiar POJOs:

```java
package net.package.dogs.retrievers

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "family")
@JsonSubTypes(value = {
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = LabradorRetriever.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = GoldenRetriever.class)
})
public abstract class Retriever {
    private String name;
    private Color color;

    public Retriever() {}

    public Retriever(String name, Color color) {
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String bark() {
        return "You can't hear me but I'm barking"; 
    }
}
```

```java
package net.package.dogs.retrievers

public class LabradorRetriever extends Retriever {
    public LabradorRetriever() {
        super();
    }

    public LabradorRetriever(String name, Color color) {
        super(name, color);
    }

    public String bark() {
        return "Ruff! Ruff!";
    }

    public String fetchDucks() {
        return "ufff...";
    }
}
```

```java
package net.package.dogs.retrievers

public class GoldenRetriever extends Retriever {

    public GoldenRetriever() {
        super();
    }

    public GoldenRetriever(String name, Color color) {
        super(name, color);
    }

    public String bark() {
        return "Wruuff! Wruff!";
    }
}
```

```java
public enum Color {
    YELLOW,
    CHOCOLATE,
    BLACK
}
```

This classes match the following JSON messages...

```
{
    "family" : "net.package.dogs.retrievers.GoldenRetriever",
    "name" : "Goldie",
    "color" : "YELLOW"
}
```

```
{
    "family" : "net.package.dogs.retrievers.LabradorRetriever",
    "name" : "Cookie",
    "color" : "CHOCOLATE"
}
```

But instead I want to have a different different "race" as follows.

```
{
    "family" : "GOLDEN_RETRIEVER",
    "name" : "Goldie",
    "color" : "YELLOW"
}
```

```
{
    "family" : "LABRADOR_RETRIEVER",
    "name" : "Cookie",
    "color" : "CHOCOLATE"
}
```

How should I fill `JsonTypeInfo` and `JsonSubTypes` to match this previous JSON message?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you could accomplish this:

1. Change the `@JsonTypeInfo` to use `JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME`:

   ```
   @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, ...
   ```
2. Add `@JsonTypeName` for name resolution:

   ```
   @JsonTypeName("LABRADOR_RETRIEVER")
   public class LabradorRetriever extends Retriever {
   ```